# Query about the the $ℓ_k$ norm, where $k$ = $0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, machine-learning

I am reading through Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras, and TensorFlow,
by Aurélien Géron.

Chapter 2 he introduces the idea of a general vector norm as follows:

"More generally, the $ℓ_k$ norm of a vector **v** containing n elements is defined as $∥v∥_k = (|v_0|^k + |v_1|^k + ... + |v_n|^k)^{1/k}$."

My confusion is about what comes next:

"$ℓ_0$ gives the number of nonzero elements in the vector, and $ℓ_∞$ gives the maximum absolute value in the vector.".

I understand how in the limit k going to infinity, the expression will return the absolute value of the vector whos magnitude was greatest,
**but I'm not sure how in the limit of k tending to 0**, the expression returns the number of non zero vectors.

Comment: Remark.  This formula defines a "norm" only when $k \ge 1$.  As noted by uniquesolution, when $k < 1$ it is often more useful without the power $1/k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write $\|v\|^k$ on the l.h.s but on the r.h.s you have $\|v\|_k$, according to the definition of the book you mentioned.
The limit of this expression as $k\to 0$  is certainly not equal to the number of non-zero elements of the vector. For example, $(1^k+1^k)^{1/k}$ tends to infinity as $k\to 0^+$, not to $2$.  What is true is that $\|v\|_k^k$ tends to the number of the non-zero elements as $k\to 0^+$. The book's comment is therefore misleading.

Comment: The book does not seem to indicate that  $\ell_0$ should be understood as a limit. However I agree with the rest.

Comment: Ive corrected the LHS:
Regarding your answer $‖‖^_ = |v_0|^k + |v_1|^k + ... + |v_n|^k$. For that to equal the number of non zero entries when k = 0, doesn't this assume that 0^0 = 0 ? According to a quick google search 0^0 = 1

Comment: $0^0=1$ is the more used convention (because it helps generalizing a lot of formulas), but it is still a convention.

Comment: Ah ok thanks, this makes more sense